# Adding unique index query taking long to run

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm recently take over a project from a vendor and it have this DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `User_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` char(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Employee_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Role_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Last_Login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `T_C` int DEFAULT '0',
  `Locale_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Warehouse_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Client_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Creation_Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_By` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Update_Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Updated_By` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sub_Client_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_ID`),
  KEY `Employee_ID` (`Employee_ID`),
  KEY `Role_ID` (`Role_ID`),
  KEY `user_ibfk_4_idx` (`Locale_ID`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `user_ibfk_4_idx1` (`Warehouse_ID`),
  KEY `user_ibfk_3_idx` (`Client_ID`),
  KEY `user_ibfk_5_idx` (`Sub_Client_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Employee_ID`) REFERENCES `employee` (`Employee_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Role_ID`) REFERENCES `access_list` (`Role_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`Locale_ID`) REFERENCES `locale` (`Locale_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

As you all see Username doesn't have unique constraints and I'm trying to add unique constraints on user table.

```
ALTER TABLE user
ADD CONSTRAINT Username UNIQUE (Username)
```

Table only have less than 10 records and query loading super long to run and not even completed.

Mysql version is 8.0.33 and it's on RDS. I did try `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` 0 and 1. But, no luck.

Anyone have experience on this ?

Comment: Is it possible, that there currently IS a duplicate, hence causing the unique index constraint to "fail"?

Comment: @dognose no, none of them records are duplicate. I'm not quite sure about FK constraints. When I remove those FK constraints, it's able to run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone having this issue, After reboot RDS and its solved the issue.